# Requirejs named module dependency

Tags: javascript, requirejs, datatables

I have a config like this:

```
requirejs.config({
"baseUrl": "/static/js/lib",
"paths": {
    // Application
    "app": "../app",

    // Libs
    "backbone": "backbone-min",
    "underscore": "underscore-min",
    "jquery": "jquery-2.1.1.min",
    "datatables": "jquery.dataTables.min",

    // Plugins
    "css": "plugins/css.min"
},
"map": {
    "*": {
        // Simple aliases
        "widget": "app/view/widget",
        "page": "app/view/page",

        "model": "app/model"
    }
}
});
```

Datatables module is defined as named module "datatables" and depends on jquery.

I noticed that Datatables trying to use jquery not from my config. Firebug network tab shows this url: /static/js/lib/jquery.dataTables.min/js/jquery.js

When I remove module name (datatables) from jquery.dataTables.js It works fine. Datatables starts to use my jquery (/statis/js/lib/jquery-2.1.1.min).

How can I make datatable to use my jquery? Its seems requirejs does not use my config when loads named modules...

Comment: What version of DataTables are you using? I've used 1.9 and 1.10 with jQuery and RequireJS without having to do anything special at all to prevent it from using the `jquery.js` file bundled with DataTables.

Comment: The last version (1.10.3). I've created a ticket on github.com. Hope the author of RequireJs will help me. Meantime I will use my fixed version of DataTables (I removed module name from the script).